# How to get the current page count?

Tags: vb6, itext

Hi i have to create a pdf document from a grid view. Thus this is the problem that i encountered. When i tried to count the total number of pages, i cant seems to get the amount.
Please help

THis are some of the coding i tried but to no avail.

```
Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A2, 50, 50, 50, 50)
...................
...................
pdfDoc.PageCount 
pdfDoc.PageSize
```

i tried to append the total page to my integer
however for the first one what ive got is that page count is a writeOnly value
while pagesize if i am not wrong is the size of the document.

Please help me thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is based on a misunderstanding of the basic concepts of iTextSharp.

A document is created in 5 steps:

1. Create a document. This document doesn't know anything about the **presentation** of the document, only about its **content**.
2. Create a writer. You are creating a `PdfWriter` that will translate the **content** into a **presentation**, more specifically into a PDF document with one or more pages.
3. Open the document.
4. Add content.
5. Close the document.

You are asking the document object for the current page number, yet the document isn't aware of its presentation. It doesn't even know that a PDF is produced.

You should ask the writer that is responsible for creating the PDF how many pages were already created; `writer.PageNumber` will return that number.

Comment: Hi I would like to add Page x Of y kind of thing at my footer.... I tried toggling with    writer.PageNumber. However i realise only at the end which is after doc.close() than im able to generate the number however i need to add the total page before that. Any one knows how to make that come about ?? I read many articles and they said using onEndPage should be able to do it but it just doesnt work for me.

Comment: Have you tried reading the official documentation? There are two different ways to solve the X of Y problem: http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=223 If you post a different question about it, I can also share some C# code. (One shouldn't post follow-up questions in a comment section.)